# Is it possible to find the Taylor series of an integral where the upper limit depends on the variable?

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, taylor-expansion

How to find the first three terms of the Taylor series around $b=c$ of

$$
\int^{\frac{1}{b}}_{a}f(b,x) dx
$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you mean the taylor series of the function $F$ where
$$
F(b)=\int^{\frac{1}{b}}_{a}f(b,x) dx
$$
Let's find the coefficients of the Taylor Series.

We know by Liebniz Rule that, assuming $f$ has a continuous partial derivative with respect to $b$ (I believe this is necessary and sufficient, please correct me if I am wrong), 
$$
F'(b)=\int^{\frac{1}{b}}_{a}\frac{\partial f}{\partial b}(b,x) dx-\frac{1}{b^2}f(b,1/b)
$$
And similarly for the second and third order derivatives. Then plug in $c$ for your coefficients.

Comment: the derivative of the function I defined in the first line with respect to $b$

Comment: What does $F'(b)$ represent here? Do you mean that $F(c)$ represent the first term and $b\, F'(c)$ represent the second term in the Taylor series?

Comment: the coefficients on the first and second term respectively, yes